# Merging two streams in RTC source control

Tags: version-control, rtc

I have two streams : sA & sB

sB was created from sA as change sets in sB were not to be included in sA.
Two paralled streams of development have been ongoing :  sA and sB

Development has now completed on sA.
sB contains changesets which are not in sA.

sA and sB are to be merged so that change sets in sA are to be included in sB but change sets in sB are not to be included in sA.

This is how I think the merge should occur :

1. Each developer who has been working on sA change their flow target to sB .
2. Each developer deliver their change sets to sB.

sB now remains independent and contains change sets which are not in sB but also contains all of the change sets where are in sA

Is this a valid approach ?

Can I deliver change sets to the stream which have been created by another developer, if so this means each developer does not have to deliver their streams as I can do it for them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is technically "valid", but I really prefer the "pull" approach:

- One integrator creates a repo workspace on `sB`.
- The flow target is changed to `sA`, in order to **accept** change sets from `sA`.
- The flow target is restored to `sB`.
- He/she merges in his/her local workspace, checkin, put a baseline, and deliver to `sB`.

That allows devs for `sA` to only have to worry about delivering to `sA`, not carring about `sB`.

Comment: does this imply that a single person is responsible for the merges/deliveries to sB ? "He/she merges in his/her local workspace, checkin, put a baseline, and deliver to sB." put another way do you mean "all change sets from sA are merged into the sB repo workspace, create a snapshot of sB and then deliver the change sets to sB" ? Also, where does "checkin" occur as part of "He/she merges in his/her local workspace, checkin, put a baseline, and deliver to sB." ?

Comment: @user470184 1/ Not necessarily: you could ask each devA to create a repo workspace on sB, and accept their change set from sA. It is still a "pull" approach, but this time, distributed amongst the devs from sA 2/ The checkin occurs whenever the merge result in local modification, leaving modified files in the "unresolved" section of your repo workspace (in the "pending changes" view).

Comment: I think its easier for each developer to change the flow target to sB and re-deliver the change sets to sB from sA repo workspace . I think this is similar to your approach except that in your approach a new repo workspace is created from sB and the change sets from sA are accepted into sB . Using your approach seems to be complicating the merge but maybe I am not fully understanding the reasons. I think the advantage of your approach is that it allows one developer to deliver all of the change sets to sB on behalf of other developers that have change sets in sA.

Comment: @user470184 I understand and respect your approach, but my view has always been: if you have a repo workspace for a stream, you should only do work related to that stream. With changing the flow target to sB from a repo workspace for sA, a devA **won't be able to deliver change set from A to sB, unless he/she first accepts other change sets delivered from other devsA to sB**. And he/she would accept those in a repo workspace initially done for working on A. That isn't good. If you merge stuff to sB, do so with a repo workspace done for sB.

Comment: @user470184 by having a repo workspace dedicated to sB, a devA will accept his/her change sets from sA, merging those in a local sandbox made from sB sources. And then he/she can deliver to sB. The second devA will be able to do the same, again in a local workspace made from sB sources, accepting and merging change sets from sA. **All the while leaving the local workspace made for sA, the one where the daily dev work for sA occurred, untouched**.

Comment: "won't be able to deliver change set from A to sB, unless he/she first accepts other change sets delivered from other devsA to sB" I was not aware of this. I suppose it makes sense to prevent a change set changing a file in another change set which is already delivered.